# How far should a wall for a bathtub extend beyond the tub?

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub, fiberglass

I am installing a new 30" wide fiberglass tub/shower kit. Does anyone have any suggestions on how wide the wall for the plumbing needs to be?

Since I am installing a 30" wide tub. Do I make the tub wall that holds the plumbing the same width as the tub, or should I make the wall 32", 33", 34", 35", 36" long?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your mock up didn't get attached

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. All information needs to be in your question, not down here.

Answer (score 2):

This is something of a preference.  Generally you would want at least 2 inches extra. (room for trim, if needed, and shower rod).  So 32 inches is a minimum.  Any size larger would be dictated by the room design, space available, personal preferences, etc.

Comment: I agree with your nominal suggestion, but generally a shower rod is inside the tub's depth. It's more a matter of the surround flange and a drywall corner.

Comment: I agree that rod placement is better inside the tub depth. However what is optimal and what is possible can be separate.  I had an instance where the enclosure was not suited to allow the expandable rods and attachment with screws was undesired.  I'm glad I had the option to mount the rod outside.  Options are good.